# How to GET xml file with request?

Tags: android, xml, json, parsing

sorry for my bad English.
I've managed how to get authorization token [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979589/how-can-i-get-authorization-token-from-browser-intent)
And now I can't get how to work with XML.
The documentation says (translating): 
get contents of /me/ resource: 
https://api-yaru.yandex.ru/me/?oauth_token=111111111111111111 
The answer will be in XML format 
Please, explain, how can I get this XML file to parse it? 
Do I need to use AsyncTask? 
 
The "dirty" code is here: http://pastebin.com/NjTiUpC5

Answer (score 1):

you need to simply append '&format=json' into your url to get response in json format

```
https://api-yaru.yandex.ru/me/?oauth_token=111111111111111111&format=json
```

in your case

```
HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
String jsonStr = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

and for get xml string

```
String xml = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
```

if you want to simply print it

and do what ever you want. good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the question. The question is about "how to be able to work with xml file with GET request?"

Comment: Sorry but part of your original message was "Please, explain, how can I get this XML file (or JSON, what's better?) to parse it?". If you still think about json see this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/9606629/1326308

Comment: if you still want to use xml read docs http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html